# 1/2 cup of brick sediment that comes down during rains - is that a big issue?

Tags: foundation, structural

I have one spot in my basement where I opened up my ceiling and have noticed what looks like a 1/2 cup of brick or mortar sediment powder coming down from the front part of my brick house on every rain.  Is that cause for alarm or time for a site inspection?  There is no insulation and it looks like it's an open air gap between the brick and the lathe and plaster all the way up.

[image]

Background: I have a 1907 brick townhouse had a gut renovation 9 years ago and they put a drywall ceiling in the basement, when we opened the ceiling to do some work, there was about a garbage bag full of sediment that came down from behind it.  Now that I've left it open, I seem to get about a cup of what looks like brick dust every few weeks - presumably after it rains.

No cracks are seen in the foundation itself, I have a brick foundation wall with dry lock on top and there is no sign of separation in the basement.

However I have noticed some cracks between the brownstone front stoop steps and the building where it looks like the front stoop steps is separating away from the building (as seen in photo below).  I haven't noticed if the crack is getting bigger or not but it looks like it was cemented over at some point and now it's about a 8mm crack that opened on top of the cement over.  Under the stoop, it looks like the mortar is pulverizinginto powder and that will need to be pointed.

Pictures of the under stoop brick and the crack in the first floor wall over the stoop.

Crack under stoop
[image: Crack under stoop]
[image: close up]
Crack under stoop close up

[image: The brick in the stoop (not the basement)]
The brick in the stoop (not the basement)

I have also noticed some drywall cracks in the ceiling in the upper floors (with no speration) and a 3-6 mm separation between the baseboards and floor boards.

Should I spend the $500 for a structural engineer to come out and do an inspection?

Comment: Not only would I be concerned about brick deterioration, should the temperature in your locale ever drop below freezing, the expanding water in cracks could cause massive damage.

Comment: A thin crack, I would usually not be concern with.  A thin crack that widens as it goes up is more concerning.  That crack seems to be in plaster/parging, so removing an inch or more and checking the wall itself would be good.  It needs repairing anyway so a bit of removing will not hurt.